# force redirection from https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I know this is a question that is asked several time.  I tried several rules but redirection of  `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` is not working.

My current redirection rule in the Apache vHost of non SSL is pasted below

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE
```

The above rule works fine for `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com`

Answer (score 1):

I find it. This needs to be added in the ssl vhost file.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

> My current redirection rule in the apache **vHost of non SSL** is pasted below
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine  on
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
> RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE
> ```

You already have a solution, but as you have found, the above redirect will obviously only apply to HTTP requests when in the "vhost of non ssl". In this case, the `HTTPS` server variable is always "off" - so the first `RewriteCond` directive is entirely redundant.

However, you don't need mod_rewrite at all when redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS in the HTTP-virtualhost. A simple mod_alias `Redirect` will do the job much "better":

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
```